# How to get the "start_lsn" value in application code

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, cdc

The database tracks all changes via the "**Change Data Capture**" mechanism. I need to add additional information about users who make these changes.
The following users are not SQL Server users. Security authorization is performed via an outside mechanism.

I want to add a helper table with columns "**start_lsn**" and "**userId**" to associate a transaction with the authorized user.
Is there any way to determine the "**start_lsn**" value, which corresponds to the current transaction executed in the application code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, I have found the following solution:

1)

- Create one more table (for example, the **"UserActivity"**), which has the **"ID"** and **"userId"** columns;
- Use the "ID" column as the Primary Key;
- Enable the CDC option for this table.

2)

- Wrap all data modification operations with a **transaction scope**;
- Add a new data record into this table with the current **"userId"** during a particular transaction:

  - Begin **Exclusive** Transaction;
  - Perform "Data Manipulation";
  - Insert Information about **"userId"** into the **"UserActivity"** table.

Since the transaction is exclusive and all operations were made within a single transaction scope, the **"last_lsn"** (**"start_lsn"**) value is the same.

After that, using the JOIN operator, merge data from the **"UserActivity"** table with Data Manipulation information.

Comment: Very clever solution.